# Pandas dataframe. Lose a part of text data when save with encoding='utf-8'

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, encoding

I'm trying to put a large list of words (in russian, unicoded) to a dataframe column and save resulting dataframe into a .csv file. I need to save encoded text, but whenever I manually set `encoding='utf-8'`, it cuts a part of my data and saves only first 100 words or something.

I'm using Python 2.7.

(lists are quite large, so here I write only the first and the last elements)

```
a = [u'\u0441\u043e\u0432\u043c\u0435\u0449\u0430\u0442\u044c', ... , u'\u044d\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0438\u0438']
s = [u'\u0441\u043e\u0432\u043c\u0435\u0449\u0430\u0442\u044c', ... , u'\u043b\u0438\u0447\u043d\u043e\u0439']


d = {'col1': [0, 1], 'col2': [a, s]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Appriciate any suggestions.

Comment: What is len(a)? Does the issue still happen if you process in chunks of 1/2, 1/4 etc?

Comment: len(a) is 164 words (1288 characters). Chunks would work well, but I don't see any convenient way of chunking a large dataset

Comment: I'm just trying to help you triage what tickles the bug. Can you confirm for what lengths the issue happens?

Comment: It seems that it leaves only 100 words (990 characters including ','). So all the strings above are being cut.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'latin-1' instead of 'utf-8'

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives `UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 6-14: ordinal not in range(256)`